# iOS: Prevent a background location service from getting unloaded when the system sends a low memory warning

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios5, background-process

I've got a location service running in the background, but I'm finding that sometimes if the user runs a number of other apps in the foreground my app will get unloaded.

Using Instruments my app currently consumes about 1.2MB in the background. A project with an empty view consumes about 600KB in the background. I know I have some improvements that can be made to bring this closer to the minimum, but beyond that is there anything else I can do to prevent my app from getting unloaded? Since my app is actually doing something "useful" in the background, is there a way to indicate this to the system so that my app will get preference some other suspended app like a game which doesn't need that memory?

Does anyone know how the algorithm works in terms of which background apps are flushed first? Is it by order of memory usage, by oldest open app in the foreground, by oldest run thread in the background?

To expand on the question:

What are the right trade-offs to be made in this service scenario? I can move my CLLocation into the AppDelegate. Should I force my ViewController to unload every time it enters into the background, such that my background memory usage is the absolute minimum, but trading off start-up time and forcing a reload of cached map tiles? Or can I wait until I get the didReceiveMemoryWarning before releasing the viewController?

If I had some sense of the order in which apps will be killed that would help to make the right trade-offs. For instance is there a round robin approach where the oldest suspended app gets the warning first. Then on coming around again if the system still needs more memory it does the actually killing? Or does the system issue the memory warning to an app, sees that not enough has been freed and than kills the app, then moves onto the next suspended app. Or is the order by memory usage?

Any best practices in on this subject would be appreciated.

Update:

After spending half a day converting my app from ARC & Storyboard back to to manual allocation, I still found that the background memory usage was roughly the same. Even though I removed all view controllers from the view and released them, the system still doesn't free that memory immediately. So in the end my app was just as likely to be killed as it was when I was using ARC. What's more interesting is that my app never gets a didRecieveMemoryWarning and my viewDidUnload never gets called, my app just gets killed without notification.

Luckily it was pointed out to me in the Apple Developer forum that if MonitoringSignificantLocationChanges is enabled even if my app is killed it will get reloaded on a significant location change.

I just had to be cognizant that my app could be re-launched from the background and had to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] to handle that event accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't stop iOS from killing your app, that's just the way the system works.
If there is a memory low memory warning iOS will kill the some of the apps that are running in the background.

Tips are just keep your memory usage as low as posible.